# How to get the Data from SQL database to few comboxes in a Form

Tags: c#, sql

**About my application**

It stores the customer information, vehicle details and service details of an automobile service center!

**What I have done**

- I have a Table in a SQL Database for storing the name of the (City, State, Pincode ......)
- I have a Form which loads the values in `TblState`, `TblCity` to the `CustomerEntry` (form)

Here is code... it works great!!!

```
private void CustomersEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Nick-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoDB;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TblState", cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;

            try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    SelectState.Items.Add(dr["State"].ToString());
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
```

**Result**

- `CustomerEntry` gets the data from the SQL and returns it in a dropdown list.
- I have a `SubForm` to add new data to the SQL database, it works fine and saves the data.

**My question**

When I try to add a new state name in the `SubForm` and save it, it is not reflecting the changes in the `CustomerEntry`, unless I close and re-open it.

Is there a way I can refresh the `CustomerEntry` as soon as the `SubForm` closes?

Comment: Can You post your code while opening the CustomerEntryform when sub-form closes?

Comment: I have used a reference in the CustomerEntry Form:

public Form RefToMmenu { get; set; }

and in the Subform i have combined the CODE to SQL and the link to CustomerEntry Form while cliking the save button.

//Here is the CODE

Comment: I have put in the answer below...follow it and you will be up and running...

Comment: // the part of the code

 try
            {
                int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (res > 0)
                {
                    this.RefToCustomerEntry.Show();
                    this.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Was Stored Successfully");
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to just refresh the dropdown when closing the `SubForm`.Put the query to refresh the drop-down data on close event of the `SubForm`... And it will be fine..

```
      private void Sub_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
     {
              CustomerEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e);
              //or it may be your logic to refresh the code on CustomerEntryForm
     }
```

Comment: CustomersEntry.ActiveForm.Refresh();   ..... will this work ??

i am sorry brother, but i am new to C# and i am learning my every steps using youtube and forums like these and its been successful till now.

Comment: can you give an example ??

Comment: @DominicDeepan.d:..added sample code ..hope you will work it out for your app now..

Comment: T.q ill sure try it and let u knw